# 2002 Jeep GC brake light issues

Tags: electrical

With headlamps on, Only top lamp works, and left tail goes out. With headlamps off, top and right brake lights work, but not the left.

Comment: Strange issue, unless there is a body control module involved, which I don't think there is for brake lights on that model. It might be a bad brake light harness connector somewhere from the brake light switch to the tail lamps, that circuit also goes through the turn signal switch, sounds like the culprit to me now that I think of it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!